# Run Magento inside a Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, magento

I have the next problem

My site have a wordpress running ( http://www.example.com ) and how im implementing magento, i wanna have http://www.example.com/magento.

I tried to do this but when i go to mysite/magento, it shows the 404 error page from wordpress. Im sure that one of  .htaccess may be the problem, but i don't know how to configure it... or if the problem is something else. basically.. Help! hahaha

Answer (score 0):

you can use Magento WordPress Integration plugin and use magento stuff in your wordpress site https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/.